# How to remove the frame of a plot in tikz but keep the axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to have a plot in tikz, with the horizantal an vertical directed axes, without numbering and without frame.

Right now my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,pst-func, pst-plot, pst-math, pstricks-add,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,clip=false,xmin=-4,xmax=4,xlabel={X},ymin=0,ymax=1] 
    \addplot[color=lime,fill=lime, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x+1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=cyan!40,fill=cyan!40, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x-1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can replace `hide axis` in your code with `axis lines=left, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty`.